# Java error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Maven on VSCODE

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception, java.lang.class

Hello i'm currently learning java i'm taking a course and we're diving into Maven proyects. The thing is that i'm getting an error when i tried to run a simple "Hello World" and my teacher couldn't find a solution

This is the code

```
package bmt;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class Saludo 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Saludo
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bmt/Saludo (wrong name: Saludo)
```

I've seen multiple solutions but I just couldn't understand them or didn't work. This only happen with a Maven proyect and if I create a CLASSPATH a "Hello World" without Maven stops working too, can someone help me please

Comment: At least you should include the steps you are doing. Without that, it's just a wild guess.

Comment: "my teacher couldn't find a solution" => Phew ...

Comment: i'm sorry did i say something wrong? what i was trying to say it was that i searched for a solution and tried changing the classpath or re installing jdk but still gives me an error and when I asked my teacher she couldn't find any solution neither.

all i'm doing its creating a new maven project. Maven > maven archetype quickstart > 1.4 version and then give it a name to the file and package, so when i try to run the code that error comes out

Comment: _"i'm sorry did i say something wrong"_ Bom dia, They forgot to say "Welcome to SO!". And your comment as an attempt of _Steps To Reproduce_ the issue would improve the Question if you'd add the additional info directly there by Editing the Question itself, as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for manual as it seems you have just started Java Programming
Since your code looks like this it includes package you have to consider it.

```
package bds;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class Saludo 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Suppose your directory looks like this

```
E:\Java\JustStarted
├───bds
└───src
```

just compile it by getting into your package

```
E:\Java\JustStarted\bds> javac Saludo.java
```

then go to the parent directory

```
cd ..
```

The console will look like this

```
E:\Java\JustStarted>
```

Now just execute the Code here by typing

```
E:\Java\JustStarted> java bds/Saludo
```

Comment: i'm sorry if its just obvious but do i create a terminal and run the route there? like C:\Users\UserName\FolderName\FileName java PackageName\Saludo? 
i didn't quite understand